# `cd` into another directory and do stuff in there

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

Using the Windows API, how can I `cd` into a directory I just created such that all new files I create will be added to that directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SetCurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Well that's simple enough. :P I'll choose yours since you were 4 s faster. :))

Answer (score 2):

SetCurrentDirectory function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365530(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You've had suitable answers, but it's normally better practice/safer to just fully qualify your filename unless you're working on a command line utility that works specifically on the current dir.
Even in that case, you can still reference files using relative path names.

Comment: In this case I think it's cleaner to change the current dir. I have a function that recursively goes through a directory tree and copies it. :)

Comment: I wouldn't say that's cleaner... There is absolutly no reason for that to change the working dir as it has all the infomration it needs to fully qualify the names anyway. It also makes it a lot more explicit. You need to use fully qualified paths for at least one side of the copy anyway.

Comment: Have to agree, changing the environment that your program runs in is not good (unless of course the purpose of your program is to change the environment).

Comment: It doesn't affect the environment, @john. [`SetCurrentDirectory` changes the working dir for the current process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Changing the working dir is absolutely fine and, in a scenario like this, probably the best way to write your code. Just be sure to put the directory back again afterwards!

Comment: @Paul Be careful with that recursive copy. Hard links and reparse points can cause you some serious headaches. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/12/27/332704.aspx